# Force both HTTPS and WWW

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

I want to force both HTTPS and WWW for my domain.

EX: `mydomain.com` should be always `https://www.mydomain.com`
Is there a way to combine both rewrite rules in ONE simple rule without affecting website stability and SEO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.mydomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via Apache too

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.example.com
  Redirect / https://www.example.com/
 </VirtualHost>

<virtualHost *:443>
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com
   ServerName www.example.com 
 </VirtualHost>
```